# Test if the ascii value of all characters of a string exists in a given range

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I need to check whether the ascii value of all the characters of a string exists in a given range say (65 to 90), the method should return true or false based on the test, how can i achieve this in objective-c?

Comment: `unichar mycharacter = [myString characterAtIndex:i];` should give the ascii character.

Comment: `NSRegularExpression`...?

Comment: Will people ever stop thinking in terms of ASCII when dealing with strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

Call the method as :

```
NSLog(@"Result: %d",[self isString:string fromASCII:65 toASCII:90]);

//Result: 1, says it is a valid string as per given range of ascii, and 0 for invalid.
```

The method is:

```
-(BOOL)isString:(NSString *)string fromASCII:(NSInteger)from toASCII:(NSInteger)to{
    BOOL isValid=YES;
    for (NSInteger i=0; i<string.length; i++) {
        if (!([string characterAtIndex:i]>=from && [string characterAtIndex:i]<=to) ){
            isValid=NO;
            break;
        }
    }    
    return isValid;
}
```